# How to call a method from my other class

Tags: java

How can I call the method step() in my Houses class.

This is my main class Ghetto that I want to call the method step in it from Houses class?

This is the whole Ghetto class:

I want the actionListener and actionPreforemd to let me call the other class

```
   package ghetto;
   import ghetto.House;
   import ghetto.Ghetto;
   import ghetto.Houses;
   import java.awt.*;

   import java.awt.event.*;

   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
   import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

   import java.util.*;

public class Ghetto extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener,
    MouseMotionListener {
protected Grids theGrid;

Panel Panel1 = new Panel(); // A panel where the cells will be laid out
JTextField sizeInput;
JTextField redInput;
JTextField blueInput;
JTextField whiteInput;
//private LinkedList<Triangle> values;
JButton stepButton;
JButton startButton;
double value1, value2;
JPanel wherePanel; //
javax.swing.Timer time; // generates ticks that drive the animation
protected double deltaT = 0.020; // how much time for each tick

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Ghetto();
}

public Ghetto() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    theGrid = new Grids(5, 0, 0);
    add(theGrid);

    startButton = new JButton("start");
    add(startButton);
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Create a timer
            time = new javax.swing.Timer((int) (1000 * deltaT), this);
            time.start();
            // Add a listener for the timer - which is the step method
            if (e.getSource() == time) 
            {
            //  Houses h = new Houses();
                //h.step();
                //Houses.step();
            }

        }
    });

    stepButton = new JButton("step");
    add(stepButton);
    stepButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // step method
            if (e.getSource() == time) 
            {
                //step();
            }
            //repaint
            repaint();

        }
    });

    sizeInput = new JTextField("");
    sizeInput.setColumns(10);
    add(sizeInput, BorderLayout.WEST);
    sizeInput.addActionListener(this);

    redInput = new JTextField("");
    redInput.setColumns(10);
    add(redInput, BorderLayout.WEST);
    // redInput.addActionListener(this);

    blueInput = new JTextField("");
    blueInput.setColumns(10);
    add(blueInput, BorderLayout.WEST);
    // blueInput.addActionListener(this);

    whiteInput = new JTextField("");
    whiteInput.setColumns(10);
    add(whiteInput, BorderLayout.WEST);
    // whiteInput.addActionListener(this);


    setSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("ActionPerformed");

    try {
        // Convert txt into a number
        int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeInput.getText());
        int blue = Integer.parseInt(blueInput.getText()) ;
        int red = Integer.parseInt(redInput.getText()) ;
        // int vacant = Integer.parseInt(whiteInput.getText());
        System.out.println("Size = " + size);
        System.out.println("Red = " + red);
        System.out.println("Blue = " + blue);
        // System.out.println("White = " + vacant);

        // remove the old components
        this.remove(theGrid);
        this.remove(startButton);
        this.remove(stepButton);
        this.remove(sizeInput);
        this.remove(redInput);
        this.remove(blueInput);
        this.remove(whiteInput);

        // create the new grid and replace theGrid
        theGrid = new Grids(size, blue, red);

        // add all of the components
        this.add(theGrid);
        this.add(startButton);
        this.add(stepButton);
        this.add(sizeInput);
        this.add(redInput);
        this.add(blueInput);
        this.add(whiteInput);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
        // sizeInput.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Comment: What does `HERE WHERE IT IS NOT WORKING` mean? Please provide _context_.

Comment: I meant that is where I want to make the change.

Comment: Houses, doesnt know what it is.

Comment: your if statement is always false

Comment: umm, it says Houses is undefined where it should know that is my other class.

Answer (score 0):

Your description does not show the whole code but I believe you have missed importing the House class in your Ghetto class, for ex,

```
import com.yourprojectname.House;
```

it would depend on your package structure and this statement is usually the second statement in a class after the package declaration. Other examples from Java packages could be

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: Can you post your Ghetto class please.

Comment: I added the Ghetto class.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I'll give an answer for anyone running into problems calling classes inside listeners. You might want to make your own listener.

Make a class, for example MyListener and do for your button

```
button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

the MyListener Class should implement ActionListener, your IDE will give you the methods to implement, you can easily call the other classes from here.